# How do I make a method accept instances with two interfaces?

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have a couple of interfaces:

```
public interface Speaker {
    void speak();
}

public inteface Walker {
    void walk();
}
```

I want a method that takes instances that are both a `Speaker` and a `Walker`.

Now, I could implement another interface:

```
public interface WalkerSpeaker extends Walker, Speaker {

}
```

And accept that:

```
void walkAndTalk(final WalkerSpeaker x) {
    x.walk();
    x.speak();
}
```

But this is quite cumbersome with many combinations, and every implementation must inherit from `WalkerSpeaker` for it to work!

Is there a better way?

Comment: This is pretty much how it is. If its becoming cumbersome you may wanna look at your design.

Comment: @Ravindrababu your answer to that link is just as cumbersome and highly rigid that cannot be expanded or changed easily.

Comment: fyi: It is good practice to use `implements` instead of `extends` for interfaces.

Comment: @Akunosh Try to replace the `extends` with `implements` and see what the compiler thinks of it.

Comment: @Akunosh An `interface` can only `extend` amother `interface`. Only classes and enums use `implements` when specifying interfaces

Comment: @Akunosh an interface can extend one or more interfaces. A class can implement one or more interfaces and/or extend a class.

Comment: The elegant solution to this "problem" is to use structural subtyping, but alas Java does not support it.

Comment: This question (and the accepted answer) is not meaningful in anyway. You are avoiding creating the interface for the **method**, yet **callers** have to create the interface anyway, including callers of the accepted answer's solution. The only way to not create the interface is to not call the method, then what's the point of having the method?

Comment: @Kayaman You don't seem to understand the comment. How are you calling the method without an extra 3rd interface? In case that still doesn't make sense, **what is your T** ?

Comment: @Kayaman how are you passing in a `T` that implements `Speaker` and `Walker` without creating an extra 3rd interface?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142184/discussion-between-poweredbyrice-and-kayaman).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can achieve this with generics as follows

```
public <T extends Speaker & Walker> void walkAndTalk(T x) {
    x.walk();
    x.speak();
}
```

The type parameter `T` will be "double-bounded" to both interfaces, so in essence `T` will be a `WalkerSpeaker` except you don't have to write a separate interface for it.

Comment: Perfect. Is there any overhead to this v.s. using an extra interface? I imagine not due to type-erasure.

Comment: Since generics are erased at compile-time, no there isn't. Not that it matters, since performance is a larger issue than some random method call.

Comment: +1, Very nice idea for this solution, but I don't like the idea that an object can be viewed with two different natures in the same method. It seems that the walkAndTalk method has more than one responsibility, so breaks the principle of Single Responsibility.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO It's basically a Java version of a [Mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) especially now with default methods. But this is just an example, so it's not very useful to consider whether it breaks some principles or not.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, this is going into a mixin-like implementation.

Comment: @sdgfsdh: well, due to type erasure, the erased type of the parameter will be `Speaker` and a type cast to `Walker` inserted at byte code level to invoke the `walk()` method, but it’s unlikely to ever notice a performance impact. The first thing, HotSpot does for performance critical code, is to inline the code into the caller’s context, where the actual type of `x` which implements both interfaces is known.

Comment: @Kayaman: If one is trying to have a method which, someone that can `Walk` and `Talk`, will navigate them to a particular location, is it more helpful to have a reference to someone that can walk, and a reference to someone that can talk, and hope that both references identify the same person, or is it more helpful to accept a reference to one person who should have both abilities, and figure that if it's really necessary to have different objects play the distinct roles (e.g. someone who can talk is in a wheelchair, being pushed by someone who is mute) one can make an artificial proxy object?

Comment: Note that nothing really is "erased at compile-time" in this code. A generic method like `walkAndTalk(T)` has *two* signatures in the java classfile: the conventional non-generic one (where the parameter is of type `Speaker` as @Holger mentioned), and the generic signature of "<T::LSpeaker;:LWalker;>(TT;)V". The full generic information can be recovered at runtime through Reflection.

Comment: you do have to write the interface for it when you **call the method**.